# Bulk creation of components in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

Let's say I need to create 100 views (with subviews, text, images, etc.) all with the same layout and stylesheets.  Is it possible to create these 100 items on the Native side, rather than create one at a time JS -> Native ?

My thought is this could eliminate any delays between JS -> Native that may add up when creating many components.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much experience you have. But I'm going to write this anyway. Ever heard of `ListView`? [Check this out](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html)

Comment: Thanks, I was overthinking the process...  I have experience with UITableViews and have seen not-so-good performance in other UITableView implementing in other JS -> Obj-C frameworks, but I think FB knows what they're doing with this one.

Comment: @ewindsor Heh. That's alright! And to be clear on my part, by experience I meant experience with react native. Good luck! Please accept my answer if it was helpful. Help a fellow programmer.